# When I use float:left in css, the text in the navigation bar menu that is pinned to the top moves a little bit

Tags: html, css

When I used float:left for css, each time I click each menu text in the navigation bar, the position of the menu text is slightly shifted. I don't know how to fix it.

The code below is the navigation bar code that goes into html. I used bootstrap.
The code below is the css code I thought was the problem. #page_num ul li in code float:left; If you erase the part, the layout of the navigation bar is not broken. But float:left; If used, the navigation menu layout is broken.

```css
li { 
  list-style: none; 
} 

#page_num {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; 
  margin-top: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#page_num ul li {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px; 
  text-align: center;
}

.fo_re {
  font-weight: bold;
  color:black;
}

.re_ct {font-weight:bold; 
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Jay.com</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="board.php">Board</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="goods.php">Goods</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link">|</a>
      </li>
      <?php if ((!isset($_SESSION['joinid'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['joinpw']))) { ?>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="join1.php">Join</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
      </li>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="basket.php">Cart</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="mypage.php">My Page</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <!-- <?php echo $_SESSION['joinname'] . ' 님, 로그인 했습니다.' ?>
      <a href="logout.php"> 로그아웃</a><br> -->
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    </nav>
```

The code I tried to solve was this, but the result was the same.

```
  li { list-style: none } 

    #page_num {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top: 30px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    }
    #page_num ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px; 
    text-align: left;
    }

    #page_num ul li::after {
    content: ""; 
    display:block; 
    clear:both;
    }

    .fo_re {
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    }
    .re_ct {font-weight:bold; 
    color:black;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to reprduce the error here. I cant reproduce it with the snippet from the code you have provided.

Comment: It's better to share the code with **codesandbox** or other services like that.

Comment: @DJHemath which is a terribel advice as it would not fullfill the SO requirements. As such the question  would be closed to lack of clarity and details. As you're new, I highly recommend to read the SO guidelines. A minimum reproducable code snipept should always be provided directly for multiple reasons.

Comment: Sure, I never read those guidelines. I appreciate for your response

Answer (score 0):

How about you do this:

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse{
    float: left;
}
```

in your css? It should work. If not:

```
.collapse.navbar-collapse{
    margin-right: -90%;
}
```